# How can we change the EHCache version internally used by Play Framework?

Tags: playframework, ehcache

I am using play 2.5.x and it internally uses EHCache 2.6.x, but I am using some of the functionalities of 2.8.8 version for the back-end code. So, while compiling I am getting error as play is not unable to find the classes specific to 2.8.8.

Is there a way to configure that without modifying the .ivy repo configuration?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.
You should make yourself familiar with the [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTDependencies)  and [library management in SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version).

Please also have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks for the info @AlexanderB (+1)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a direct dependency of your project to ehcache 2.8.8 in build.sbt, that should be used. The version 2.6.x should show as evicted during compile. However, in case the play implementation is not compatible with 2.8.8, it will break.